# Simulate package-privacy on properties in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, visibility

So, I have an enum called `Level`. That enum is actually just a wrapper for some other Level. Now I need to access that wrapped value (currently a `protected` property) in a different class called `Log` which sits in the same package. Obviously I do not want to completely expose that property by making it `internal` or `public`, but I need to access that wrapped value in my Log class.
How to I do that?

As Kotlin doesn't provide anything similar to package-private visibility, everything I tried failed. I'm already aware of the possibility to put both classes in one file, but that only allows me to gain exclusive access to the classes themselves, not their properties. And because I need to have both classes public that won't help either. So if anyone knows a workaround, I would be more than happy to hear it, because even though I really like Kotlin, this might be the reason for me to drop the language.

Both classes I mentioned look as follows:
Level.kt

```
enum class Level(protected val level: java.util.logging.Level) {
    /** Useful for stuff */
    OFF(CustomLevel("OFF", Int.MAX_VALUE)),
    ASSERT(CustomLevel("ASSERT", 1200)),
    FATAL(CustomLevel("FATAL", 1100)),
    ERROR(CustomLevel("ERROR", 1000)),
    WARN(CustomLevel("WARN", 900)),
    INFO(CustomLevel("INFO", 800)),
    DEBUG(CustomLevel("DEBUG", 700)),
    ALL(CustomLevel("ALL", Int.MIN_VALUE));

    private class CustomLevel(name: String, value: Int) : java.util.logging.Level(name, value)
}
```

Log.kt

```
object Log {
    private val DEFAULT_CONSOLE_VERBOSITY = Level.ERROR
    private val DEFAULT_FILE_VERBOSITY = Level.ALL

    @JvmStatic
    var consoleVerbosity: Level
        get() = Level.findLevel(consoleHandler.level)
        set(value) {
            consoleHandler.level = value.level // The property I need to access
        }
    @JvmStatic
    var fileVerbosity: Level
        get() = Level.findLevel(fileHandler.level)
        set(value) {
            fileHandler.level = value.level // The property I need to access
        }

    private val consoleHandler = ConsoleHandler()
    init {
        consoleHandler.formatter = SimpleFormatter()
        consoleHandler.level = DEFAULT_CONSOLE_VERBOSITY.level
    }
    private val fileHandler = FileHandler()
    init {
        fileHandler.formatter = SimpleFormatter()
        fileHandler.level = DEFAULT_FILE_VERBOSITY.level
    }
}
```

I am running the latest stable version of Kotlin (1.4.31)

Comment: I love Kotlin, but this is to me it's biggest drawback. Please upvote the [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-29227). There should at least be a `file-private` visibility.

Comment: I agree! File private would at least allow me to put both classes in the same file and get the wanted functionality, even though being somewhat dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you may define an extension function/property for `Log` class in the scope of `Level` class:

```kotlin
enum class Level(private val level: java.util.logging.Level) {
    //...
    
    //Option 1
    companion object {
        fun Log.getLevelOf(level: Level) = level.level
    }
 
    //Option 2
    val Log._level get() = level
}
```

Also you may define extension property for `Level` class in the scope of `Log` class for more natural usage:

```kotlin
object Log {
   //...

    private val Level.level : java.util.logging.Level
        get() = consoleHandler.level = Level.run { getLevelOf(this@level) } // For Option 1
        get() = with(this) { _level } // For Option 2
}
```

Downside of this approach is a tough coupling between these classes.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use extension functions like this:

```
fun Level.toLevel() = this.level
```

That allows you to access protected properties of other classes.

Comment: Extension functions can't access protected or private members.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a private class from another class but you can access a class from a class that is packed inside a file. So the workaround is to make fun in public class to access the private class which is in the same file.

But the highlight is that you cannot write a class inside an enum class in Kotlin.

I still don't know how you managed to write this code down in an IDE, because it will show an error.

Comment: The code actually throws a NPE because of faulty enum constant initialization. Upon fixing that the code runs just fine, so private classes are definitely possible inside enums.

Comment: Just for clarification: I do not want to access `CustomLevel`. I want to access "protected val level" which is not of type "CustomLevel" but of `java.util.logging.Level`.